# Calculating the Lyapunov exponents spectrum from particle trajectories

Tags: flow, non-linear-systems, chaos-theory, complex-systems, turbulence

I am simulating a forced, compressible 2D flow, that is turbulent and statistically steady, but not stationary.
I want to calculate the Lyapunov exponents spectrum from the trajectories of Lagrangian tracers injected into the flow. As output I have $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ of each particle, so I basically have my data in phase space.
Is there a straightforward way of calculating the spectrum? Should I treat it as Wolf's experimental time series?

Answer (score 1):

You first need to realise that there is a considerable difference between:

1. The dynamics describing your flow and how it changes over time.
2. The dynamics of a particle subjected to the flow.

To illustrate this, consider a perfect stationary circular flow. Here Dynamics 1 is clearly a fixed-point dynamics, while Dynamics 2 is periodic. Even worse: For every typical chaotic system (e.g., the Lorenz system), you can imagine a stationary fluid flow that reproduces its phase-space flow. Here the particles would exhibit a chaotic dynamics, while the flow itself is fixed.

In the following, I first assume that you care about **Dynamics 1**.

The Wolf algorithm is made for experimental time series.
It has several shortcomings originating from experimental constraints, that you do not have on account of working with a simulation, in particular:

- Where the Wolf algorithm performs a Takens reconstruction of phase space, you have access to all dynamical variables.
- Where the Wolf algorithm needs to use the next-best observed state in a certain direction, you can just simulate a state with the exact properties you need.
- The Wolf algorithm can only handle moderately low-dimensional dynamics, while a turbulent flow is probably rather high-dimensional.

Probably, the most straightforward option would be to use orbit separation with orthonormalisation:

1. You simulate your dynamics simultaneously together with ones for slightly perturbed initial conditions, one for each Lyapunov exponents. The difference between the perturbed dynamics and the original roughly correspond to the Lyapunov vectors.
2. Roughly every oscillation, you estimate the (local) largest Lyapunov exponent from the growth of the largest Lyapunov vector (normalisation).
3. For every further exponent, you remove all projections along larger Lyapunov vectors (othogonalisation) and then normalise as above, obtaining estimates for the respective local Lyapunov exponents.
4. Repeat until you have a proper statistics and average your local Lyapunov exponents to global ones.

If you have easy access to the Jacobian of your dynamics, you can apply the algorithm from [Benettin et al.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02128236) (also described in [Wolf et al.](https://doi.org/10.1016/0167-2789(85)90011-9). The above method is the same except that it does not operate in tangent space.

Finally note that either way, your Lyapunov spectrum will be large as you have any many exponents as variable required to describe the state of your flow. Reconsider whether you actually need the entire spectrum or only the non-negative ones.

If you care for **Dynamics 2** instead, you have to consider that it is at least as high-dimensional and chaotic as Dynamics 1 as it is completely driven by it. Thus all of the above problems apply. In particular if you want to apply the Wolf algorithm to only the particle trajectories, you would be throwing away a lot of important information and make your life fundamentally more difficult as you would now reconstruct a high-dimensional dynamics from two observations only.

What you can do here is to keep the dynamics of the flow fixed and apply an orbit separation to different particles starting with close initial conditions (at the same state of the flow).

> As output I have x(t) and y(t) of each particle, so I basically have my data in phase space.

This is not correct. The future of a particle does not only depend on its position but also the current state of the flow. If you would apply the Wolf algorithm (or any other method) to this without accounting for this, you get garbage results.

Comment: I am only interested in the largest and second largest Lyapunov exponents to calculate the Lyapunov Dimension. It is possible to get the flow dynamics and use that for the Jacobian but I want to use the particle trajectories instead because I'd like to get the Lyapunov exponents estimated from Lagrangian trajectories. That is why I was looking into the Wolf et al. method.

Comment: Are you sure that that’s what you really need? As for everything else, see my edit.

Comment: Thank for your help! I will try orbit separation on different particles with close initial conditions. I want to link the flow compressibility to the Lyapunov dimension from particles to link the particle distribution to the flow dynamics (similarly to what has been done with the compressible Kraichnan flow). Analytically, it is quite hard to do so we are trying numerically.